# Need help understanding c++ windows for a Java guy

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

Thing is I'm learning how develop Win32 applications in C++. I'm using Visual Studio and windows.h and I'm having a bad time. 
I come from Java and Android, where you create a class like MainWindow or OptionsWindow and then you write inside the behavior and instantiate them whenever you want.

But now I'm in C++ and I'm lost. 
All examples I see with windows.h library are codes where Main is WinMain inside the window. So, here's is my question: Is there any way where you write different classes for different windows and instantiate them when you need it? something like

```
 OptionWindow ow = new OptionWindow
```

Or should I write all the code of every window I will need inside the WinMain and then make it visible?

Help Is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why dont you start with wpf or winforms?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I'm open to any suggestions. I haven't look for that options. Pros and Cons over windows.h? I'm using It because is the default approach of Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't just start trying to write C++ based on some examples and your knowledge of Java. You will make a nasty hash of memory leaks, inefficiency, and frustration. C++ is really very little like Java. Get a book like _Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++_ and learn C++ first. Then you'll be able to use C++ properly. One last thing to keep in mind: in C++, if you're using raw pointers much at all, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know C++ approach for everything is very different than Java. Lucky for me I know program in C so I know the basics of pointers etc. Also I'm using a book named Jumping into C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are committed to using just C++, I'd recommend creating a C++/MFC Application with VS2013. Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) was a framework that hides much of the drudgery of creating and manipulating windows. It is much easier to get started with than raw Win32 programming.

MSDN has a number of [tutorials and articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9es9d1k4.aspx)  that may help you get started. I also found this reasonable [step-by-step guide](http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorial/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/index.html) to MFC programming. If you search for MFC Programming you should find a fair amount of information/code/examples.

Since you are using Visual Studio 2013 one suggestion by commenters isn't applicable to you. There is a suggestion you could use C++/CLI (it is effectively .NET C++). C++/CLI is often a shim that is used as a gateway for C++ developer migrating to C#. Microsoft no longer supports Winforms through the IDE for C++/CLI applications. There is no longer a Winforms application project for C++/CLI either. If you have VS2010 winforms is availale through the IDE.

If you are writing a GUI and don't wish to use MFC with C++ I would recommend jumping to C#. Find a good book on the subject. Microsoft has an [online guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228602(v=vs.90).aspx) that is for Java developers migrating to C#.

Based on the OPs comment that he'd like to do things more programatically. There is a solution that was created by Microsoft and is still maintained by the open source community. That option is Windows Template Library (WTL). I personally still use it for light weight applications where I don't want to overhead of MFC. It is a set of Windows templates that sit a top ATL (Active Template Library). ATL was originally designed as a set of C++ templates to build reusable binary components using COM.

You can add WTL to VS2013 (it is not part of standard Visual Studio anymore). You can download WTL from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/ . Installation is not straight forward but it does work once installed properly.

Comment: HI! I just discovered that previous answers does not work anymore on VS13, as you say. Jump to C# is not an option. I'm preparing myself for an special degree in c++. Ideal thing for me is have the control I have in Java, build all by myself writing size, position etc etc and be able to instantiate a window like any other object. I'm against GUI's to develop. Thank you for answering

Comment: MFC can be done programmatically without the GUI. The GUI just makes it easier. MFC Window functionality is encapsulated in C++ MFC classes. I will admit it is a much different paradigm than Java.

Comment: I have amended my answer with some information on WTL that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Winapi uses a plain C interface, so there are no premade classes available.

If you want to write .net Applications in C++ you can use wpf (Windows Presentation Foundation) or winforms as huseyin wrote in his comment.

If you want to develop native win32/64 applications you have to use a library/framework. Microsoft has the [MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library), but IMHO they are complicated and thus don't like them.

You also could have a look at cross-platform frameworks as qt, gtk or wxWidgets. However there you have to take care the license (qt is available as GPL, LGPL or a commercial license, so you either have to buy developer licenses, put your code also under the GPL or comply with the LGPL).

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. I will have a look on those. I did look into Qt, but I always like to code everything myself. I can see now that's not an option anymore.Thanks.

Comment: I think "complicated" is probably a matter of perspective. I am comfortable using them (and I do C# WPF, QT, GTK development as well) MFC at least has no licensing issues, and there is a plethora of documentation and books on the subject. And it works with the authors chosen language MS C++.

I should point out that after VS2010 if you program C++/CLI - not even Winforms is even available through the IDE as Microsoft has made it clear C++/CLI is meant for interop solutions, not a feature complete .NET language.